# restrict: 'E' is not working

Tags: angularjs, directive

this is my first try to write a directive.....and i tried to do my best.

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="APP">
     <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <title>Custom Directive</title>     
     </head>
     <body>

          <personName fname="Debditya" lname="Dasgupta"></personName>



     <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
     <script src="app.js"></script>
     </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var APP = angular.module('APP',[]);
APP.directive('personName',function() {
     return{
          restrict:"E",
          link:function(scope,element,attrib){
               scope.fullName = attrib.fname + " "+ attrib.lname;
               console.log(scope.fullName);
          },
          replace:true,
          template:"<h1>{{fullName}}</h1>"
     }
});
```

My problem is that directive not rendering anything.  Why is the directive not rendering correctly?

Comment: Your directive in HTML should be `person-name`. Read about normalization.

Comment: Oh....you made my day...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code appears to be working :) in your dom, just change 
      `<personName>`
 to `<person-name>` :)

Answer (score 0):

**personName** in your HTML should be **person-name**, from Angular documentation:

```
The normalization process is as follows:

1- Strip x- and data- from the front of the element/attributes.
2- Convert the :, -, or _-delimited name to camelCase.
```

See [Normalization](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) for more details